# Displaying raster image (tiff, img, hdf) using gdal, Tkinter?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, tkinter

I am building modis data processing tool in python. I am building GUI using Tkinter and installed various geospatial library. i have tried to visualize image using matplot lib but it is showing image in new window. i want make tool like QGIS, or GRASS.

How do they build raster viewer?

installed python 2.7.13, GDAL/OGR, Numpy, (all basic lib).

Comment: You could use a Canvas with a PhotoImage, if you have converted your Numpy array to an image using e.g. Pillow.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about it, you *can* embed matplotlib inside a Tkinter canvas. There's an example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html